# Текст из Button

Tags: java, android, button, textview

Имеется 1 активность, в ней 2 кнопки, 1 TextView, 2 строковых ресурса. При нажатии на кнопку1, текст из нее(строковый ресурс кнопки1) достается и устанавливается на TextView, при нажатии на кнопку2 - все аналогично(только строковый ресурс другой). Для простоты пока разделил на две кнопки. В дальнейшем кнопка будет одна, она будет после нажатия менять свой строковый ресурс текста и в зависимости от ресурса, он будет устанавливаться в texView.

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button btn = (Button)v;
        String btnText = btn.getText().toString();
        if (btnText.equals("Left")) {
            tv.setText(R.string.btn_left);
        } else if (btnText.equals("Right")) {
            tv.setText(R.string.btn_right);
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
};
```

Пробовал доставать через getResources().getString(), но что-то не получилось. Пока текст в .equals() установлен жестко, т.к. запихивая туда R.string.btn_left/right не срабатывает.

Сделал так и все заработало:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btn_left;
Button btn_right;
TextView tv;

String leftStr;
String rightStr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn_left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn_left.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn_right.setOnClickListener(this);

    leftStr = getString(R.string.btn_left);
    rightStr = getString(R.string.btn_right);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button btn = (Button)v;
    String btnText = btn.getText().toString();
    if (btnText.equals(leftStr)) {
        tv.setText(R.string.btn_left);
    } else if (btnText.equals(rightStr)) {
        tv.setText(R.string.btn_right);
    } else  {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
}
```

Есть какие-либо замечания по данному коду?

Comment: Если вы в активити, то достать строку из ресурсов можно просто `getString(R.string.app_name)`  Но не совсем понятно, что у вас именно не работает?

Comment: Немного переписал код. Необходимо добиться того, что метод onClick срабатывал в зависимости от текстового ресурса, который сейчас привязан к кнопке.

Comment: 1) У Вас OnClickListener привязан только к двум кнопкам зачем вобще if? tv.setText(btn.getText().toString()); раз уж на то пошло. 2) Если вы он кликлистенер привяжете к другой вью  (например заходите реализовать клик по текствью) у вас упадет программа с ошибкой КлассКастЭксепшн, так как не сможет преобразовать вью к Баттон. Я к тому что нужно делать так как принято и рано или поздно Вы все равно придете к тому, что в OnClick будете брать id вьюшки и на основании этого выполнять требуемое действие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно по идентификатору строкового ресурса получить строку и передавать уже ее, а не идентификатор

```
    getString(R.string.btn_right)
```

И устанавливать в TextView уже строку

```
    tv.setText(getString(R.string.btn_right));
```

Конкретно в Вашем случае я бы привязывался к id кнопки, зачем вью приводить к баттон, брать текст из баттона и сверять его. Смотрим какой баттон нажали и устанавливаем в ТекстВью соответствующую строку:

```
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    tv.setText(MyActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.string1));
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    // делаешь то, что нужно сделать при тыке на кнопку 2
                    break;
                default:
                    // все остальные вью, для которых установлен данный листенер
            }
        }
    };
```

Опять же создавать отдельный листенер не принято, лучше у Активити реализовать интерфейс OnClickListener

```
  public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

Ну и реализовать метод OnClick

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    // делаешь то, что нужно сделать при тыке на кнопку 1
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    // делаешь то, что нужно сделать при тыке на кнопку 2
                    break;
                default:
                    // все остальные вью, у кого в качестве листенера установлена данное активити
            }
        }
```

останется в качестве листенера кнопки подцепить активити

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Да, примерно так себе и представлял, но дело в том, что позже будет одна кнопка, и надо будет менять текствью, в зависимоти от строкового ресурса на кнопке.

Comment: Хорошо, а строковый ресурс на кнопке от чего зависит? 
От какой-то переменной скорее всего! Что мешает эту переменную обрабатывать в листенере и в зависимости от нее выводить текст?

Comment: Делать условие на основание строкового ресурса - это извини говнокод какой то ИМХО

Comment: Я исправил весь код повыше, гляньте и выскажите свое имхо)

Answer (score 0):

Вы свич по строке делаете, исправьте на

```
switch(v.getId())
```

Comment: Это подошло бы, если бы я пытался определить по какой кнопке произошло нажатие, а так, кнопка одна - 2 строковых ресурса.